# jQuery HeapBox "this" inside of events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, heapbox

I've selected a plugin called [HeapBox](http://www.bartos.me/heapbox/) in order to style some `select` dropdown menus.

This plugin doesn't add any information as to the state of the box (open or closed), but it does have events, such as `openStart` and `closeCompleted`.

My implementation is as follows:

```
$( 'select' ).heapbox( {
   'openStart' : function( ) { $( this ).addClass( 'open' ); },
   'closeComplete' : function( ) { $( this ).removeClass( 'open' ); }
} );
```

However, `this` is undefined. I'm trying to understand why `this` does not refer to the object instance for the custom select element.  It seems like it is a standard boilerplate, but it appears the events don't have a reference to the related heapBox.

Has anyone else used this plugin before and is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, without modifying their source code?

Comment: @m90 Good idea, but there is nothing to bind to here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to touch the vendor code you could use [`fn.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a bound version of your handler function. Note that you would need to use `$.fn.each` to iterate over your `select`s then:

```
function openHandler(){
    $(this).addClass('open');
}
function closeHandler(){
    $(this).removeClass('open')
}

$('select').each(function(){
    $(this).heapbox({
       'openStart' : openHandler.bind(this),
       'closeComplete' : closeHandler.bind(this)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Taking a look at the src for the heapbox plugin, it is using call() without any parameters to invoke those functions. E.g.:

`this.options.openStart.call();`

If you wanted `this` to refer to the select element, it would need to be modified to read:

`this.options.openStart.call(this.element);`

You can modify the plugin yourself and make these changes or request them of the creator

Comment: Thanks this is precisely what I was after. I was trying to avoid modifying the source, but sometimes that's inevitable. Sounds like I should make a recommendation to the author, as well. Thank you for you input.

Comment: Also, in case anyone uses this plugin, I'm passing `this` into the call, instead of `this.element` (which refers to the original select element, not the heapBox element). Then, in the events, I am able to use `$( '#heapbox_' + this.instance.heapId )`, similar to how the plugin source does.